# SQLITE table is corrupt - had typo in migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I generated a bad migration and the file looked like this

```
class AddActivexToMat < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :mats, :is_active, :boolean
    add_column :mats, :default, :true
 end
```

end

Without checking the migration file, I ran rake db:migrate and now my schema reads

```
# Could not dump table "mats" because of following NoMethodError
#undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I tried to remove columns but getting the following errors

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
```

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass/Users/jhorsch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:215:in`column'

I don't think changing the columns will work either and I am afraid to drop the table.  I don't think I can just drop a table and add a new one with the same table name.  In this case the table name was 'Mats'

Luckily this table only had one previous column 'name'

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please provide full backtrace of errors?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8oFPPVq.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you specify incorrect column type here:

```
add_column :mats, :default, :true
```

`:true` is invalid column type.

Comment: exactly..that is what corrupted the data table